# Vetor do tipo string em C

Tags: c, array, string, for, printf

Oi, gente! Eu tenho dúvida em relação a um vetor strings em C. É possível criar um vetor em C com, por exemplo, o nome de 5 pessoas, **e cada nome representa um índice do vetor**, e depois mostrar na tela esses nomes? porque quando eu tento fazer isso não da certo. Não aparece nada na tela. Exemplo de código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char *dias_da_semana[] = {"Samuel", "Roberto", "Laura", "Larrisa", "Jonas"};
   
   for (int i=0; i<strlen(*dias_da_semana); i++) {
       printf("%c", *dias_da_semana[i]);
   }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria Possível Você Criar com uma Matriz. Ex.: dias_da_semana[5][20]. Aonde o [5] Representa as Linhas, ou a quantidade de Nomes que Deseja, e [20] Representa a Quantidade de Caractere que você queira que a String tenha. Assim Você pode Acessar cada Nome da String Percorrendo cada Índice de Linhas da Matriz. Segue um Código como Exemplo.

---

#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

```
char dias_da_semana[5][20] = {"Samuel", "Roberto", "Laura", "Larrisa", "Jonas"};

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

    printf("%s\n", dias_da_semana[i]);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Muito obrigado!